# give focus to datagrid after button is clicked

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, focus, focusmanager

I have a button and a datagrid. They are located on the same window. I need to give focus to selected row after the button is clicked. Seems to be not as straightforward as I've thought.

So I've got a DataGridRow object. I call DataGridRow.Focus(), but the focus is still there.
After reading this [incredible topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052389/wpf-reset-focus-on-button-click) I've tried using FocusManager to loose focus on the button, also tried settings Button.IsFocusable = false and then setting to true back again. Also tried giving focus to my row using this:

```
var scope = FocusManager.GetFocusScope(MyDataGrid);
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(scope, row);
```

But it didn't help. Probably I do not understand how FocusManager works well enough. Could someone give me a clue how to give focus to a row?

Comment: what happens if you `DataGrid.Focus()`, then `DataGridRow.Focus()`; OR `DataGrid.Focus()`, then `DataGrid.SelectedIndex = -1`, `DataGrid.SelectedIndex = indexOfRow`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
row.Focusable = true;
row.Focus();
```