# Button needs to be clicked twice due to textbox lost focus

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, lost-focus, updatesourcetrigger

I have a textbox which has UpdateSourceTrigger = LostFocus.

When I type something in textbox and immediately click on button, the button click event does not fire. I think textbox simply loses the focus to button. When i click on button again it fires click event.

How to overcome this issue?

Here is my XAML code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="ApText"
                         Width="135"
                         Margin="0,4,0,0"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top"
                         Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{DynamicResource UI.ErrorTemplateStyle}" />

<Button
                    Width="100"
                    MinWidth="60"
                    MinHeight="40"
                    Margin="0,8,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                    Content="Save" />
```

Comment: can you please provide a sample of your xaml

Comment: check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052389/wpf-reset-focus-on-button-click

Comment: updated my xaml code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution for this.
Just changed Clickmode of Button to Press. And voila its working.

Updated Code:

```
<Button
                    Width="100"
                    MinWidth="60"
                    MinHeight="40"
                    Margin="0,8,0,0"
                    ClickMode="Press"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
                    Content="Save" />
```